# How to make a timed input that triggers other "events"?

Tags: python-3.x, time, user-input

Know first, that I am relatively new to python.
I am trying to make a program that in a certain time(5 seconds) asks for a certain input. If the program doesn't get an input within 5 seconds, overrule the input and trigger a print. If it is done in 5 seconds, trigger another print.

I'm trying to edit this code to suit my program. Help, please.

```py
import time
import threading
import os
import signal

class FiveSec(threading.Thread):
    def restart(self):
        self.my_timer = time.time() + 5
    def run(self, *args):
        self.restart()
        while 1:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            if time.time() >= self.my_timer:
                break
        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)


def main():
    try:
        t = FiveSec()
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        while 1:
            x = input('::> ')
            t.restart()
            print('\nYou entered %r\n' % x)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nDone!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This program however just kills itself after not receiving input and continues in a loop that I have no clue to break.